# Extend front porch deck 7"

Tags: deck, porch, extension, skirting

[image]
We are building a small cabin and the pier blocks are extending 4.5 inches past the face of the deck framing. When we were building, we didn't think of it, but now that we are in finishing stages and want to put skirting on, we are running into a problem with the outward taper from the pier blocks. If we were to do it over again, we would have cantilevered the deck an extra foot to accommodate the skirting and trim. Any suggestions here?

Some possible solutions we have (although not very ideal) are cutting the skirting around the pier block taper, planting scrubs or placing planter boxes in front of pier blocks (approximately 6" with deck board overhang of .75 and 5/8" of trim). What about screwing PT boards onto the front to make up the width of the desired overhang using lock tight deck screws?

Comment: One more idea for you: make those steps the full width of the porch. Put some planters down the middle to break up the width.